# How do we create a generic object using JAXB in java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I wish to map or transform this xml into a java object and I want to extract the "body "element in the xml and make it  generic java object. I do not want to map each field. I just want the whole request body with all the elements. How do I do that?

```
<request>
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soap:Header xmlns:dpwsm="http://www.reuqestpower.com/schemas/ryesbs"
                         xmlns:g="http://www.request.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <k:SoapHeader>
            </k:oapHeader>
        </soap:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <purchaseOrderRequest xmlns="http://www.somecompany.com/order/PO
        xmlns:addr="http://www.somecomapany.com/order/ADDR>
        <firstname>Fred</firstname>
        <surname>Bloggs</surname>
        <addr:address">
            <addr:addressLine1>2 South Road</addr:address1>
            <addr:addressLine2/>
            <addr:town>Colchester</addr:town>
            <addr:county>Essex</addr:county>
            <addr:postcode>CO8 9SR</addr:postcode>
        </addr:address>
        <telephone>01334 234567</po:telephone>
    </purchaseOrderRequest>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
</request>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [DOM Parser](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm) and then examine the nodes:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
Node body = dom.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("SOAP-ENV:Body").item(0);
for(int i=0;i<body.getChildNodes().getLength();i++)
{
    System.out.println(body.getChildNodes().item(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can or want to use a third party library, you could use [`Jsoup`](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document):

```java
org.jsoup.nodes.Document dom = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
Element body = dom.getElementsByTag("SOAP-ENV:Body").get(0);
for(Element child:body.children())
{
    System.out.println(child);
}
```